# Author uses Proposition 2 of Book 6 of Euclid's Elements, what does this mean?

Tags: geometry

In the book *Plane Trigonometry*, by SL Loney, the author is proving that the ratio of a circle's circumference to its diameter is constant, i.e., that the ratio always equals $\pi$. [image]

[image]

The attached image is the author's proof in its entirety. I understand the proof until the author writes "Then, but Euc. Vi. 2, abcd... is a regular polygon of n sides inscribed in the smaller circle." Now, by saying "Euc Vi. 2," the author is actually referencing the second proposition of Book 6 of Euclid's *Elements* (linked here: [https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookVI/propVI2.html](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/elements/bookVI/propVI2.html)).

The proposition basically proves that the sides of a triangle are cut proportionally by a straight line if and only if that line is parallel to the remaining side of the triangle. I really don't see how this fact implies that abcd... is a regular polygon inscribed in the smaller circle. I understand pretty much the rest of the proof other than this small detail.

Comment: Right.... So as $AB = BC = CD =DE =EF .......$ and $ab|| AB, bc|| BC, cd||DE ......$ it follows by Vi. 2 that $ab=bc=cd=de=ef.....$

Comment: sorry if this sounds stupid, but I still don't understand.

Comment: Well $\frac {AB}{ab} = \frac{big\ radius}{small\ radius} =\frac {BC}{bc}$ and as $AB=BC$ we must have $ab=bc$.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now

Comment: Glad I could help.  However the lines where he says "let the number of sides be indefinately increased" uses hand-waving that I don't think would be considered acceptable today.

Comment: Interesting, why is that? Does this make the proof wrong?

Comment: No, it doesn't make the proof wrong as proofs are only arguments meant to convince. But convince whom at what level. Have you ever seen the proof that $\sqrt 2 =1$? Draw a line from A to B of length one. Divide it into $n$ segments.  On each segment draw a sawtooth. The length of each side of one sawtooth is $\frac {\sqrt 2}{2n}$. The length of the path of going up and down all sawteeth is $n\times 2(\frac {\sqrt 2}{2n})=\sqrt 2$. Now if we let $n\to\infty$ we get that the path is still $\sqrt 2$.  But if $n=\infty$ the path is the same thing as the line which is length $1$.  So $\sqrt 2 = 1$.

Comment: I haven't seen that specific one before, but I have seen one that says pi equals four. You draw a square perfected circumscribed around a circle of diameter 1, so the square length is 1 and perimeter is 4. Then you fold the corners of the square so it goes around the circle completely, and thus the perimeter remains the same: 4.

Comment: That's the same error and the same idea.

Comment: This is my last question I swear...while the proportion you provided does make sense, the author makes an equivalent one, and when he states this in the proof, he cites proposition 4, not 2.

Answer (score 1):

The polygon $ABCDE........Z$ is regular so $AB =BC =CD =......$.

The triangles $\triangle OAB$ and $Oab$ and $OBC$ and $Obc$ and $OCD$ and $Ocd$ etc are all isosceles so $ab||AB$ and $bc||BC$ and $cd||DC$ etc.

So by comparing $\triangle OAB$ to $\triangle Oab$ we see $AB||ab$ so by Vi.2 we have $\frac {AB}{ab} = \frac{OA}{Ob} = \frac{\text{radius of big}}{\text{radius of small}}$.  But we can do that for all the triangles so $\frac {AB}{ab} = \frac {BC}{bc} = \frac {CD}{cd}$ etc.  And as $AB=BC=CD=.....$ we have $ab=bc=cd.....$

Comment: Now I understand, thanks for the help.